# How to integrate $\int dv/(1+\sqrt v)$

Tags: calculus

How does one integrate $$\int \frac{dv}{1+\sqrt v}$$? Do I replace $\sqrt v$ with something $u^2$ so that I may get arctan? Or should I do something else?

Comment: [Maple](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=examples/Calculus1SingleStepping) can be used to this end, especially the [IntTutor](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Student/Calculus1/IntTutor) command.

Answer (score 4):

If we set $v=u^2$ then we get $dv=2udu$ then $$\frac{dv}{1+\sqrt{v}}\to\frac{2udu}{1+u}$$

Comment: Needs another TU +1

Comment: Oh my shame!!! Why did not I notce such this very bad mistake??!! Thanks! many thanks

Comment: +1 You're welcome @Mikasa

Answer (score 2):

Replacing $v = u^2$ is a good idea. You'll get $$\int_0^x \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{v}} \mathrm{d}v = \int_0^{\sqrt{x}} \frac{1}{1+u} 2u\; \mathrm{d}u = \int_0^{\sqrt{x}}\Big(\frac{2+2u}{1+u} - \frac{2}{1+u}\Big) \mathrm{d}u, \; \; x \ge 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Set $\sqrt{v} = u$ which is the same as $v = u^2$. Then that means $dv = 2udu$ and plug that back into integrand to get: $\int\frac{2u}{1+u^2}$. You should be able to do the rest on your own. :)

Comment: But $\sqrt v = u$ so isn't the denominator 1+u..?